# Height of a principal ideal generated by a zero divisor.

Tags: commutative-algebra, ideals

> Let $A$ be a f.g. algebra over a field $k$. Let $x$ be a zero divisor of $A$. Does it follow that $\mathrm{ht}(x)=0$?

I know that by Hauptidealsatz ht(x)$\leq$1.

Comment: Hauptidealsatz would be translated as "(Krull's) principal ideal theorem" by the way

Comment: You're right. But what about the problem?

Comment: I have no clue.  However, since this is a primarily English-speaking site, my comment is likely be helpful to someone who could give you an answer

Answer (score 3):

No. Let $R=k[x,y]/(x^2,xy)$ and let $I=(y)$. Then $I$ has height $1$ since $I^2=(x,y)^2$, but clearly $y$ is a zero divisor in $R$.